# Recording Mobile browser operations using Jmeter tool

Tags: jmeter

I need to record the mobile browser operations  using Jmeter tool. How do I do this?

and also I need to record file download scenario for one of the website using mobile browser under different network conditions (WiFi, 3G and 2G)
Can I record the file downloading scenario? If yes, please let me know how do I do that.

I need to run this file downloading scenario for 20 times with 1 user. Is it possible?

Pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

1. For mobile browser recording - make sure that the host running JMeter and mobile device are on the same network and device is configured to use JMeter host as a proxy. For step-by-step guide see [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide.
2. To simulate different network types you can change `httpclient.socket.http.cps` property value in *jmeter.properties* file. See [How to simulate network bandwidth in JMeter?](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks) wiki page for details and values for different network types
3. Simulation of downloading a file 20 times is possible with [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) test elements combination. See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) post for instructions